Getting a callback on layers user selects/clicks PyQGIS
layer = iface.activeLayer()
name = layer.name()

if name == 'zoning': 
    iface.messageBar().pushSuccess('Selection correct', 'Well done')
else :
    iface.messageBar().pushCritical('Incorrect selection', 'Try again')

This is my code so far which just gives a warning when layer named 'zoning' is not selected. However, I want to make this work when the user clicks or selects a layer instead of running the script.

Put most of your logic into a slot function and connect it to iface.currentLayerChanged. This signal also emits the layer object which you can catch. Just be aware the layer object can be a nullptr (None in Python) so you will want to check for that.

I was also searching for this.  @Ben W I think is pointing to something like this.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a QGIS layer object
        self.layer = QgsVectorLayer() 

        # Connect the currentLayerChanged signal to the on_layer_changed slot
        self.layer.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.on_layer_changed)

    @pyqtSlot(QgsMapLayer)
    def on_layer_changed(self, layer):
        # This slot is called when the current layer changes
        print("Current layer changed to:", layer.name())

PYQGIS signal for layer tree when active layer changed

No, the currentLayerChanged signal is emitted by the QgisInterface and QgsLayerTreeView classes, not by any layer object, so this would result in: AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'currentLayerChanged'. Also not sure why you are sub-classing QMainWindow here. In any case, I think the (already answered) question you linked to is similar enough that I'm closing this as a duplicate.
